# Need Help in Fixing Force Close Issue in Android?

Tags: android

Hai Friends,
           I have created an sample application, in which i have a list view, when the user clicks the listview the next intent is called with no problem in sometimes, but most of the times it display Force Close or Wait Message as shown in the Image attached here, i want to stop displaying this Force Close or Wait Dialog, I have no idea how to stop this warning message, so guide me, to stop this.
Pls refer my output
![alt text][1]
Pls refer my Logcat Message

```
10-28 16:30:54.640: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(76): getLocation(): triggering a wifi scan
10-28 16:30:55.410: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(76): updateWifIScanResults(): 5 APs
10-28 16:30:55.430: DEBUG/LocationMasfClient(76): getNetworkLocation(): Returning cache location with accuracy 75.0
10-28 16:31:05.220: DEBUG/dalvikvm(15032): GC freed 15 objects / 600 bytes in 124ms
10-28 16:31:05.690: INFO/ActivityManager(76): Stopping service: com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.googlenav.friend.android.LocationFriendService
10-28 16:31:09.960: DEBUG/WifiService(76): ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED pluggedType: 2
10-28 16:31:13.186: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(76): wakeWhenReadyLocked(82)
10-28 16:31:13.190: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(76): handleWakeWhenReady(82)
10-28 16:31:13.190: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(76): pokeWakelock(5000)
10-28 16:31:13.250: DEBUG/WifiService(76): ACTION_SCREEN_ON
10-28 16:31:13.430: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(76): Screen about to return, flinger = 0x1896a0
10-28 16:31:15.610: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(76): pokeWakelock(5000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is shown when you block the GUI thread (your only thread if you didn't created others by hand) for a long time. If you have some code in your activity that does a lot of work or sleeps for a long time, you should move this code to another thread.

I would suggest measuring the time taken by all your activity methods.

Comment: Thanks for ur Comments: You have suggested that measuring the time taken by all your activity methods, pls elaborate this, that is i am asking how to achieve this,pls show me some good samples.

Comment: You can use the profiler, here you have a complete explanation that I have elaborated last month: http://organicandroid.blogspot.com/2010/09/performance.html

Comment: Or if you prefer official developers word: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/10/traceview-war-story.html

Answer (score 0):

If you figure out where you are doing the heavy work you can split it out into another thread and then call back to the UI thread when your finished so you can then fire your Intent.

```
 public class ExampleActivity extends Activity

   private ProgressDialog mDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      mDialog= ProgressDialog.show(ExampleActivity.this, "Please wait...", "...", true);
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                         // Do some long loading
                         // and then
                         mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1); //Notice the 1 in the switch statement
        }
    }).start();
  }

 public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            switch (msg.what) {
                case 1:
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    // Your back in the UI thread
                            // Fire whatever method you want
                break; 
                default:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Handler on got message that wasnt dealt with");
                break;
            }
        }
    };
  }
```

On a side not I can see your doing an iPhone conversion, remove the back button ... not needed nor pleasant on a UI

Answer (score 0):

I hope you understand what blocking the GUI thread meant.
You can try doing heavy and time taking operations like network activity inside a handler too, if you want.

Comment: @Ruben I read your post but possibly it doesn't work without a permission prior to Froyo. If we're using 2.1, then we'll have to provide some permission to our app. Am not sure, though, what that permission is. can you please tell? is it: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry, I have just seen this comment, I feel that StackOverflow doesn't recognize twitter style references.

Comment: Yeah.. it doesn't, at least till now. Comments and Answers don't work the twitter way. :-)